# How to use properly raw_input with math operations

Tags: python

I was trying to play around with raw_input and dind't got any much of success.
Basically the idea is to sum, minus, and multiply two different numbers.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = raw_input()
    b = raw_input()

print(a+b)
```

So it says that I need to define raw_input.
I was wondering if there's any way to input from the console 2 numbers randomly.
As far as I know raw_input stores the data in the system?

Comment: What version of Python?

Comment: Was trying with 3.6.5, but seems it was removed in pyhton3 so I was wondering if there's any other way to do it.

Comment: @bl4ckch4ins I think you are misunderstanding a few things. `raw_input` in python 2, is nearly identical to `input` in python 3, I'm assuming that you are on python 3 and that's why you are getting it confused.

Could you elaborate on what you mean by "to input from the console 2 numbers randomly" I'm not sure what would be random about console input. @Irfanuddin's answer would suffice if you simply are trying to convert console input into numbers then add them.

Comment: Python 3.x doesn't have a `raw_input()` function. Use `int(input())` or `float(input())` for numeric values. See [PEP 3111](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3111/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = input()
    b = input()

print(a+b)
```

Comment: Oh thanks I know, I can do it as well with different formats, but the I wanted to play around with raw_input, thanks.

Comment: `raw_input()` is removed in Python 3.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Is there any other way to do it? or only by input.

Comment: `input` is, for all intents and purpose, the equivalent of Python 2 `raw_input`. Python 2 `input` was the equivalent  of `eval(raw_input())`, which is why Python 3 dropped it.

Comment: @Vikas : It would be good to include some description to your answer which would let OP/other users know what's the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Python3 has no `raw_input()`. The `input()` function is equivalent of the previous one.

If you want to add the numbers or perform any other arithmetic operations, you have to convert to an Integer or float.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = int(input())
    b = int(input())
    print(a+b)
```

If you want the operation to happen endlessly, simply put it inside a `while True` loop.